# Joomla 3.5 error an error has occured

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

After updating from 3.4.8 to Joomla 3.5 I get the following error message

[image]

Although i am unsure what the error even is, what is being affected

```
<div id="system-message-container">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                <div class="alert alert-error">
                <h4 class="alert-heading">Error</h4>
                <div class="alert-message">An error has occurred.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

enabling debug mode gives an overwhelming information which nothing obvious is present.

I am happy to keep ignoring this however it shows on every page in the admin area.

I rolled back and updated to 3.5 with the same issue. other than disabling every extension has anyone dealt with this issue?

Comment: This is no longer an issue, possibly after update to 3.5.1

Comment: Yes its a joke, the Joomla developers hate us, and so they removed any useful info from the error report like file, line, call trace before displaying it to us mockingly.

Comment: The joke is if your still using Joomla, i switched over to laravel and productivity is off the charts!

Comment: Thats a framework like codeignitor, Joomla is a CMS like wordpress

Comment: I was building Components, modules and plugins. The lines start to get fuzzy

Answer (score 1):

From the *exhaustive* information you posted, the only things we learn are:

1. There is some kind of error
2. It happens on every page.

With this plethora of information, we can only assume a plugin is responsible, or a module which shows on each page.  I bet you it's a system plugin.  Open extensions/plugin management, filter by "system" type, and disable - re-enable the plugins one by one until the error goes away.

Grab an updated version of the plugin that has issues, et voilà.

Still not fixed?

1. Rule out the modules
   just rename the administrator/modules directory, reload, if the error is still there, rename back.
2. So it's in the plugins? 
   rename plugins/system to something else, and you'll see it go away. If it doesn't try other categories such as content etc.

btw the error logs / debug mode most likely show what's wrong.